# Can Sends be Moved to new Categories (Folders)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api

I have a bunch of sends for a project at the root of our account (Tracking > Sends). I'd like to move them all (identified by Send ID) to subfolders. Ideally, this would be done programmatically. Is there a recommended SOAP or Fuel API way to move Sends to a new Folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way you can move sends like that (Cut Paste I mean)
You can always put them in a separate data extension if you like but that would be an additional copy

Comment: I was able to move Lists to new folders (categories). I wonder why this wouldn't exist for Sends.

Comment: Sends is run time data that is captured when you send an email. That is technically the tracking data which is stored in internal tables of SFMC and is linked to so many other areas in the system.
Lists on the other hand is what you create